# what kind of questions about tool and software library are on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons

I have encountered quite a few questions about programming tools and libraries that are voted for close as asking recommendation for " book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource"

One example is [this close review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/8272673?filter-closereason=offtopic) about a question asking where to download previous version of some tool/library called `Werkzeug`.

In my book, such questions are valid as programmers sometimes have to back-track to earlier version of developer tool if current versions have problems.

Furthermore, I think the question is on topic because, the person clearly already knows the library because he is asking for a previous version. That's why I don't think he/she is asking a **recommendation** for certain libraries or tools to achieve something. And I can't see any ground for closing such a question.

As I see more and more questions closed under the reason of asking recommendations for tools and library, I was wondering if there are some complimentary rules and guidelines about what aspects of a software tool/library is on topic?

I guess, the more general question I have is, how can this particular close-reason be used properly without making the mention of a tool a tabu.

Answer (score -1):

The guidelines for "close voters" are really clear and unambigous about this - you quoted them, and that is what is not allowed.

Sometimes the close-vote-queue reviewers will cut some slack when it seems in the best interests of ... something, but to the letter of the law there are no exceptions.

There is nothing written down that I'm aware of that backs your assertion that "some {of these} questions are valid as .... {whatever}".

They simply aren't valid, because the rules say so, and if they are allowed to stay its because someone is making a call that it's in the best interest of ... us *despite* the rules.

Note that I'm not in any way saying whether I think that the rules are good and right, it's just what they are.

If we are going to systematically allow some kinds of requests for off-site resources, then we should write down what those are.

Comment: Even real laws are subject to interpretation. I really don't understand the dogmatism about SO rules here.

Comment: Having clear rules, and then allowing interpretation are two separate things.  The OP asks "what are the rules".   As I said, they are very clear.   As I also said, interpretation, and exception are quite regularly applied by plenty of pragmatic reviewers.   (So, also, is dogmatism by pedantic reviewers, I'll grant you that)

Comment: I think you probably quote it wrong about ` The OP asks "what are the rules"` and probably oversimplifying about what OP is really asking.

Comment: " I was wondering if there are some complimentary rules and guidelines about what aspects of a software tool/library is on topic?"  ... this is the question I was answering.   The answer is "the rules are clear, and pragmatic judgement is (sometimes) exercised in applying them".